# Is "What did you doing?" the wrong way to say it?

Tags: grammaticality, usage, past-continuous

I often hear English native speakers say:

> What did you doing?

Is that really ok to say?

Isn't it supposed be:

> What are you doing?

Or is it a contraction of other sentence?

Comment: No, "What did you doing" is certainly not correct, but I dare doubt native speakers would use it. Could it be that you misheard it?

Comment: My guess is you misheard "Whatcha doin'?" or some other reduction of "What are you doing?"  Native speakers don't say "What did you doing", as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3):

I never hear anyone who is a native speaker say "What did you doing?". They either say "What are you doing?" or "What did you do?". Perhaps you heard wrong, or they aren't native speakers.

"What did you doing?" is incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to think of any way the O.P. might have heard this from a native speaker. The best I can come up with is someone asking a question like, "What did you **do in** the Navy?" and the O.P. mistakenly thought it was "What did you *doing* the Navy?"

Comment: That makes sense, and happens often learning a new language and not being able to separate words properly.

Comment: Thanks for answers! Probably they were saying "What are you doing?" very fast and I thought it was "What did you doing?"